# ¿Cómo sé si una unidad mapeada es persistente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo una función en C# que lee las unidades mapeadas en el sistema y muestra una lista de las unidades de red. Para ello estoy usando `ManagementObjectSearcher` con una consulta que me devuelve las unidades lógicas mapeadas.

He estado mirando las diferentes propiedades y no encuentro ninguna que indique si esa unidad es persistente o no (algo que parece sí estar disponible si es una unidad online). ¿Existe alguna propiedad para ver la persistencia de la unidad mapeada? Si no, ¿cómo se podría comprobar?

El código que tengo se ve así (simplificado):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

class MappedDrive
{
    public char Letra { get; }
    public string Ruta { get; }
    public bool Persistente { get; }

    public MappedDrive(char Letra, string Ruta, bool Persistente)
    {
        this.Letra = Letra;
        this.Ruta = Ruta;
        this.Persistente = Persistente;
    }

    // devuelve una lista de las unidades mapeadas en el sistema
    public static List<MappedDrive> getUnidadesMapeadas()
    {
        List<MappedDrive> unidades = new List<MappedDrive>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher buscador = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
        foreach (ManagementObject unidad in buscador.Get())
        {
            unidades.Add(
                    new MappedDrive(
                        unidad["Name"].ToString()[0],
                        unidad["ProviderName"].ToString(),
                        true // <--- Esto es lo que no sé cómo leer
                    )
                );
        }

        return unidades;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MappedDrive> du = getUnidadesMapeadas();

        foreach (MappedDrive unidad in du)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: mapeada a {1} (persistente: {2})", unidad.Letra, unidad.Ruta, unidad.Persistente);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `unidad["Persistent"]` no vale? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586167/3045491 (es vb.net )

Comment: Probé con `unidad["Persistent"]` (tenía que haberlo puesto en la pregunta, lo siento) y me da una excepción porque no se encuentra una propiedad con ese nombre

Comment: oh vaya, y por que en vb.net si que tiene esa propiedad?

Comment: No es que esté en VB.net y no en C#.net, es porque yo estoy leyendo `Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` y el otro ejemplo está leyendo de `Win32_NetworkConnection`. Me pidieron que añadiera una opción para ver si la unidad es persistente, pero no sé si es algo que sólo las unidades de red tienen

Comment: Cierto! no me fijé en la consulta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` desde luego no tiene ninguna propiedad que indique si es una unidad mapeada es persistente. Supongo que tendrás que obtener la ip de la unidad remota y buscarla en `Win32_NetworkConnection`. Algo parecido a este código, no esta muy probado y puede depender de las unidades, pruebalo y comentame a ver si te ayuda.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher buscador = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");


foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject unidad in buscador.Get())
{
     var path= unidad["ProviderName"].ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     ManagementObjectSearcher buscador2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_NetworkConnection where RemoteName like '%" + path[0] + "%'");
     var persistent=buscador2.Get().OfType<System.Management.ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault()?["persistent"];
     if (persistent!=null)
     {
          unidades.Add(
                new MappedDrive(
                    unidad["Name"].ToString()[0],
                    unidad["ProviderName"].ToString(),
                    (bool)persistent
                )
            );
     }
     else
     { 
          //no se encontró unidad de red
          unidades.Add(
                new MappedDrive(
                    unidad["Name"].ToString()[0],
                    unidad["ProviderName"].ToString(),
                    false
                )
            );         
     }
}
```

**Edit**

Si no funciona con las propiedades que indico (que funcionan en unidades de red), se puede probar cambiando "Name" por "LocalName", y para la ruta "ProviderName" por "RemotePath".

Comment: Hola Pikoh, una pregunta, ¿a qué se refiere la variable `path`? Supongo que te refieres a `unidad.Path`, aunque `unidad.Path` devuelve un *string* y no un *array* :)

Comment: Fijate que hago un `Split` para quedarme solo con la primera parte del Path @Flxtr

Comment: Ah ok ok, entonces en lugar de poner `var unidad = ...` sería `var path = ...`, de hecho, unidad ya existe en el contexto actual con la declaración del `foreach`

Comment: Tienes razon @Flxtr me acabo de dar cuenta. Lo he editado ;)

Comment: ¡Vaya!, lo he probado y sí funciona :D solo encontré dos detalles: el signo de interrogación está de más `FirstOrDefault()?["persistent"];` y la variable `persistent` obtiene in `object`, por lo tanto, al agregarlo a la clase debe ser con un casteo implícito `(bool)persistent`, fuera de eso, va de maravilla :D

Comment: @Flxtr el signo de interrogacion está para que no de una excepción en el caso de que el 'Get´ no devuelva resultados (necesita .net 6.0 si no recuerdo mal). En cuanto a castear a bool,tienes razon,edito :)

Comment: Usando `Win32_NetworkConnection` se solucionó mi problema. Eso me sirvió de mucho (aunque debo reconocer que no termino de entender parte del código que pones). Como detalle, en `Win32_NetworkConnection` para obtener la letra de la unidad no es `"Name"` sino `"LocalName"`, y para la ruta no es `"ProviderName"` sino `"RemotePath"`. Por si quieres actualizar tu respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, en mi caso que las rutas eran de red las propiedades eran `Name` y `ProviderName`. Edito la pregunta para aclarar esto, me alegro de que te sirviera :)